Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/vikrant/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/vikrant/.docker/run/docker.sock.

Please search your question rather than feel the need to create a new post for a self answer.

Issue
When running the command:
docker ps

I encounter the following error:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/vikrant/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Solution
To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

Set the Docker Host: Set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to point to the default socket location:
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock


Purpose: This command directs the Docker client to connect to the standard socket where the Docker daemon listens for commands.


Create a Symbolic Link: Create a symbolic link from the Rancher Desktop socket to the standard Docker socket path:
sudo ln -s /Users/vikrant/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock


Purpose: This command allows the Docker client to access the socket used by Rancher Desktop, ensuring compatibility with Docker commands.



Summary
By setting the DOCKER_HOST environment variable and creating a symbolic link, you can resolve the connection issue and enable the Docker client to communicate with the Docker daemon successfully.
Additional Notes

Ensure that the Docker daemon is running before executing the docker ps command.
If you are using Rancher Desktop, verify that it is properly configured to run the Docker daemon.

